# Suggestions For Waterproofing a Basement with Infrequent Seepage

Tags: basement, waterproofing

After a particularly strong rainfall (every ~3 years), water seeps into my partially finished basement from small gaps in the intersection between the wall and floor.

[image: Areas where the water seeps in]

The amount of water is significant.  Last time (a couple of weeks ago), it was about 6 gallons.

The floor and walls are poured concrete, with the wall having a coat of plaster.

The issue only occurs on one wall.

I've looked into a drainage / grading solution, and I don't think I can solve the problem there.  With these rainfalls, half of my backyard will be underwater, and a nearby intersection can get about 2 ft. of standing water.

The side of the house with the issue has good grading (by my assessment), 8 ft. gutter extensions, and is a side of the house that the roof doesn't slope onto.

[image: Outside of the house]

Based on responses to other questions on this site (    [How can I stop this water from entering my basement?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29935/how-can-i-stop-this-water-from-entering-my-basement?rq=1) and [I have a basement floor with lots of moisture, can I paint or seal it to make it waterproof?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/i-have-a-basement-floor-with-lots-of-moisture-can-i-paint-or-seal-it-to-make-it?rq=1)), it seems that an ideal solution would be a foundation membrane, but I can't afford that, and the problem isn't severe enough to warrant that expense.

So, I'm wondering if using hydraulic cement in the wall-floor gaps would be enough to stop the water.

[image: Close up of one of the openings]

The gaps are small, so I believe I'd have to chisel out a larger gap to install the hydraulic cement properly.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on that idea or other suggestions.

If it makes any difference, my house does not have a sump pump.

Comment: I don't think anything you can do on the inside will solve the problem. Hydraulic cement may reduce the amount of water entering but it may force it in other areas.

Comment: Sounds like you have a high water table and it is seeping in after a large amount of rain. You might need a sump drain system.